# Quickblox sample videochat - can not create user

Tags: android, chat, quickblox, videochat

when creating new user the app displays "error creating new user, Please try again" 
and i get this in log [log screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWOPp.png) 
what could be the problem and how can it be solved.

Comment: @Daniel Please add it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your application has exceeded the API call limitations for your current plan.

From the [quickblox FAQ](https://quickblox.com/plans/):

> #### What happens if I exceed the limitations?
>
> Some requests will be denied (throttling). For example, if you're on the free tier and sending 25 push notifications per second, 5 of those requests will be denied and the notifications will not be sent. We will soon be offering usage statistics in the admin dashboard to show you how much you're using and whether you need to upgrade or not.

You can find a list of available plans on  https://quickblox.com/plans/